# DB2 Joining a Large Physical table with a small Global Temp table

Tags: db2, mainframe, db2-zos

I have the below requirement of Joining 3 tables

```
a) Table T1 - large physical table with 100 Million rows
   Index columns: C1, C2, C3 in this order
b) Table T2 - Temp table with 50 records
   contains C2 & additional columns. No Index
c) Table T3 - Temp table with 100 records
   contains C3 & additional columns. No Index
```

Tables T2 and T3 have no common columns

I tried to extract data from T1, T2, T3 as below:

```
Select T1.*, T2.*, T3.* 
from T1 
Inner join T2 (on T1.C2 = T2.C2) 
Inner join T3 (T1.C3 = T3.C3)
where 
T1.C1 = a constant value (coming from my program).
```

Explain of above query shows that on T1, Index scan was performed using only 1 column. (I believe it is T1.C3 as i provided WHERE clause)

The query is executing fine but taking slightly longer.  Is there a better way to code the query for above requirement?

Any inputs are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You mention you're using a temp table.  Did you run RUNSTATS on the temporary tables, ***including*** collecting column statistics?

An index scan matching on one column has to be against T1 matching on column 1, since that is the leading column of the index.  When examining explain, you should also pay attention to PRIMARY_ACCESSTYPE.  Db2 may choose to scan one or all of T1, T2, and T3 and create a sparse index, which would be reflected with PRIMARY_ACCESSTYPE = T in the PLAN_TABLE.

What is the cardinality of the 3 column index on the 100 million row table?  Is it unique?  Is it highly selective - close to table size of 100 million rows, or would significant duplicate rows qualify for every probe?

Accurate statistics are important in this scenario.  The cost of cartesian join is quite high, so it's important Db2 understands how small the temporary tables are, and how selective the join columns are in considering the access path to choose.  If no statistics are collected on tables T2 and T3, Db2 by defauls assumes 10,000 rows in a table.  Then a cartesian join of T2 and T3 would be estimated at 10,000 * 10,000 rows = 100 million, then it would make sense for Db2 to just access that table once using the local filter, then join to T2 and T3, possibly with a sparse index.

If collecting statistics does not resolve, please update the question with plan table results.